Solving PDE's involving lagrandian
I'm trying to solve this $PDE$:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)Z(x,y)+\alpha^2Z(x,y)=0 $$
I feel like this involves a Bessel J function but don't know how to approach it. What's the principle here? How is it solved?
I tried converting $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ but didn't find anything either. Your help and guidance would be very appreciated0

Maybe clarify the domain and boundary conditions of interest.

If you do not specify the boundary conditions there will be infinitely many solutions. If your goal is to find this you can try to separate the variables setting $Z(x,y) = X(x) Y(y)$.
